# Create a filter list of items where a filter item appears only if there is a story for the product

Tags: filter, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to figure out how to create a filter list where it grabs the product title from a _products directory and it will show the title in the list only if there is a story with the title of the product.

I have a _products list with 11 items and I can show them all, but I want to remove an item from the list of filter items if it's title != a element in the front matter of a list of stories in a separate directory.

```
{% assign product = site.products %}
            {% for product in site.products %}
             {% for success in site.success-stories %}
                {% if product.title == success.product %}
                 <li><p class="filter label label-default" data-filter=".{{product.title | downcase}}">{{product.title}}</p></li>
                {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
```

What this does is shows only the items that have a matching success-story but if there are multiple stories with the same product in it's front matter it will show that product more than once.

I've got the filtering down, it's just showing the items I can't get down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling you are looking for the `contains` filter.
Taken directly from the [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) wiki:

> ```
> # array = 1,2,3
> {% if array contains 2 %}
>    array includes 2
> {% endif %}
> ```

In your case, I'm guessing you want:

```
{% assign product = site.products %}
{% assign successfulProducts = site.success-stories | map: 'product' %}
{% for product in site.products %}
  {% if successfulProducts contains product.title %}
    ... {{ product }} ...
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

All I've done here in line 2 is [mapping](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#map) `success-stories` to `successfulProducts`. Essentially each `story` element is replaced by its `story.product` property.

Then I loop through all the products like you and check each one if it should be displayed. But I don't loop through all the stories - instead I put a simple condition that checks if `successfulProducts` contains the product title, just as you specified.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it out and it worked. Thanks for explaining it well to! :)